# glibc, possible race condition between closing FILE* while exiting?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I've distilled a larger program down to the code shown at the bottom. Running this program in valgrind will eventually report this error:

```
==7234== Invalid read of size 4
==7234==    at 0x34A7275FC8: _IO_file_write@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.15.so)
==7234==    by 0x34A7275EA1: new_do_write (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.15.so)
==7234==    by 0x34A7276D44: _IO_do_write@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.15.so)
==7234==    by 0x34A7278DB6: _IO_flush_all_lockp (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.15.so)
==7234==    by 0x34A7278F07: _IO_cleanup (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.15.so)
==7234==    by 0x34A7238BBF: __run_exit_handlers (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.15.so)
==7234==    by 0x34A7238BF4: exit (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.15.so)
==7234==    by 0x34A722173B: (below main) (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.15.so)
==7234==  Address 0x542f2e0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 568 free'd
==7234==    at 0x4A079AE: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:427)
==7234==    by 0x34A726B11C: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.15.so)
==7234==    by 0x40087C: writer (t.c:22)
==7234==    by 0x34A7607D13: start_thread (in /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.15.so)
==7234==    by 0x34A72F167C: clone (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.15.so)
```

From the above output, this seems to be what's happening:

- main() returns, and starts running the exit handler to close all FILE*
- the writer() thread, still running, wakes up, closes a FILE*
- the exit handler tries to access the closed FILE*, which is now invalid/free()'d

As far as I can tell, the test program doesn't do anything undefined, but I'd be happy to be wrong on that.

Valgrind hooks into various functions, so it is possible it is a valgrind bug and not glibc.

- is this a glibc bug ?
- Or is it a valgrind bug ?
- Any ideas on how to determine whether it's valgrind or glibc ?

t.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *test(void *arg)
{
    return NULL;
}
void *writer(void *arg)
{
    for(;;) {
        char a[100];
        FILE *f = fopen("out", "w");

        if(f == NULL)
           abort();

        fputs("Test", f);

        if(fgets(a, 100, stdin))
            fputs(a, f);
        fclose(f);  //line 22
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t tid1,tid2;


    pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, writer, NULL);
    pthread_create(&tid2, NULL, test, NULL);
    pthread_join(tid2, NULL);
    //pthread_join(tid1, NULL); //no bug if we wait for writer()
    return 0;
}
//compile: gcc t.c -g -pthread
```

May take several minutes to trigger an error from valgrind, with:

```
while [ true ]; do 
  echo test |valgrind --error-exitcode=2 ./a.out  || break  
done
```

Environment: Fedora 17, glibc-2.15, gcc-4.7.0-5, kernel 3.5.3-1.fc17.x86_64 , valgrind-3.7.0-4

Comment: What is the real problem here?  That valgrind complains?  You already know the correct handling is to join tid1 (possibly after encouraging it to terminate with a flag).

Comment: @walrit The problem is that either valgrind, glibc or the program has a bug, and I'd like to know which. This is a _very_ simple test case - it's not always feasible to halt all threads while exiting - and it'd be a plus if exiting a multithreaded doesn't cause the runtime to trash memory.

Answer (score 4):

You have a race condition. You have a thread that calls `exit`, which is documented to close all open stdio streams. You then have another thread that, potentially after `exit` has closed it, accesses such a stream. You cannot access a `FILE*` after it's closed -- it is permitted to point to garbage.

If a thread does something that makes calling `exit` unsafe, you must ensure you don't call `exit`. It's really that simple.

Comment: I'll agree that could be a race condition. The output seems to show the opposite though, that the runtime accesses a FILE* after it's closed. And I'd question the need for all the complicated locking glibc goes through here if it doesn't prevent things like this.

Comment: It's impossible for `glibc` locking to prevent this -- the pointer becomes invalid. You can implement a global count of things that are in progress that prevent an exit. Then set an "I want to exit" flag. Wait for the count to drop to zero, then call exit. Other threads check the flag before starting such things and increment the count while exit must not be called. (Often, clean shutdown is not worth the trouble and you should just cleanly shutdown what needs a clean shutdown and then call `_exit`.)

Comment: @David: POSIX requires `exit` to be thread-safe. The potentially unsafe act is calling a stdio function that acts on the stream during `exit`. I don't see anywhere the atomicity of `exit` is well-defined. At least from a quality-of-implementation standpoint, however, it should be impossible to observe a point where `exit` has closed any streams but the process has not terminated. This is easy to achieve when implementing stdio, too: just flush streams without actually closing them (the final `_exit` will close the fds anyway) and leave them locked after flushing to prevent further io.

Comment: Note that we make this guarantee (that stdio during `exit` is safe and that no operation on a file is possible after it's been flushed) in musl, and the code is trivial: http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/stdio/__stdio_exit.c

Comment: @R.. Honestly, I think that's a bad idea. Had the OP been using musl, he never would have caught this bug and it could have caused some very serious problems in the future if the code was used on other platforms.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug in the OP's code, but it's ambiguous since there's no statement of the atomicity or non-atomicity of `exit`. This really calls for a request for interpretation and clarification of the standard.

Comment: @R..: The bug is that his code accesses a stream after it closes it. There is no possible way `exit` could be atomic in the sense that once `exit` began, no other thread could execute at all. If it prevented other threads from running, it would hang if it needed to acquire a lock held by another thread. And if it forcefully terminated other threads first, `atexit` handlers would be unable to do things like shut those threads down cleanly. Plus, forcefully terminating threads corrupts the process context, making a clean exit impossible.

Comment: There are many possible ways that `exit` can be atomic from any observable standpoint. Lack of imagination does not imply lack of existence. Note that I'm talking about behavior *after* `atexit` handlers are called, since obviously they can't be atomic. Simply obtaining locks on every resource it will need as its very first step, then stopping all other threads, should be one way to achieve it.

Comment: @R..: Then we're talking about portions of `exit` being atomic, since calling `atexit` functions is part of what `exit` does.

Comment: Yes. Sorry I wasn't clear in stating that from the beginning.

Comment: I believe you've actually stumbled across two bugs in POSIX. One is this race condition issue (is it intended to exist? probably not...). The other, which is separate issue but closely related, is that it's unclear how file locking interacts with closing streams at exit. For instance, if a thread does `flockfile` on any file, does that block all other threads from calling `exit`? What if it's just doing a `getc` that blocked waiting for input (thus holding the file lock)?

Comment: @R..: I'm not sure I'd go so far as to say they're bugs in POSIX, but they're definitely wrinkles that make a clean shutdown much more difficult under conditions that I think most people would consider entirely reasonable.

Comment: Many of the designs in POSIX threads are documented as having been chosen to make it possible to use threads transparently in library code without the main application having to be aware of this or care about it. But if you can't use stdio without worrying about `exit` causing your use of files to invoke UB, that means you pretty much can't use stdio, period. Considering how much effort (and painful requirements on the implementation that make stdio a lot slower) went into making stdio thread-safe, I think this is a bug.

Comment: small update, it looks like a bug much like R.. mentions. A Red Hat employee have added it in the glibc bugzilla ,http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14622