# Is it possible to use exit in thread?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, asynchronous, exit

I put `exit()` into a thread, but my program does not exit some times.

according to this [link](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html), `exit()` is not `async-signal-safe`. I'm wondering if the use of `exit()` in a thread causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: Check out `exit_group()` or `_exit()`.

Comment: I guess `exit()` is only meaningful for a single-threaded process.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce in the debugger? You need to see what the program is doing. It might be deadlocked, live locked, or in some infinite loop because it is walking a corrupted data structure (or some equally bad state).

Comment: `exit` is supposed to end the whole process and if you call it from any normal thread it should do just that. Please give us more information about the calling context that gives you trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Ordinary `exit` (as opposed to `_exit` for instance) needs to do all the usual `atexit` cleanup, output-flush, etc., work.  It *is* possible to construct code that hangs in some cases, but I had to make an "obvious problem" to show it.  If a library routine (e.g., internal stdio `fflush`) is attempting to grab a lock (e.g., on a stdio stream) in the exiting thread that some other thread is holding, it might be possible to get a similar hang even without your own `atexit`.  Since you have not shown your code I am merely speculating.

Here's a test program (with deliberate, obvious issue) that hangs when told to, at least on FreeBSD.  (Formatting tricky because cut and paste kept tabs but then I had to edit some into spaces...)

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

pthread_mutex_t global_mtx;

void die(int error, const char *fmt, ...) {
    va_list ap;

    va_start(ap, fmt);
    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    if (error)
        fprintf(stderr, ": %s\n", strerror(error));
    else
        putc('\n', stderr);
    fflush(stderr);
    _exit(0);
}

enum behavior { NORMAL, EXIT_WO_HANG, EXIT_W_HANG };
struct behave {
    enum behavior how;
    pthread_mutex_t lock;
    pthread_cond_t cond;
    int th1_entered;
    int th2_entered;
};

void hanger(void);

void *th1_main(void *);
void *th2_main(void *);

#define WR(x) (void)write(1, x, sizeof(x) - 1)

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int error;
    struct behave how;
    pthread_t th1, th2;

    error = pthread_mutex_init(&global_mtx, NULL);
    if (error)
        die(error, "pthread_mutex_init global_mtx");
    error = pthread_mutex_init(&how.lock, NULL);
    if (error)
        die(error, "pthread_mutex_init how.lock");
    error = pthread_cond_init(&how.cond, NULL);
    if (error)
        die(error, "pthread_cond_init how.cond");
    how.how = NORMAL;
    how.th1_entered = 0;
    how.th2_entered = 0;
    if (argc > 1) {
        if (strcmp(argv[1], "exit") == 0)
            how.how = EXIT_WO_HANG;
        else if (strcmp(argv[1], "hang") == 0)
            how.how = EXIT_W_HANG;
        else if (strcmp(argv[1], "normal") != 0)
            die(0, "usage: example [normal|exit|hang]");
    }
    atexit(hanger);
    error = pthread_create(&th1, NULL, th1_main, &how);
    if (error)
        die(error, "pthread_create th1");
    error = pthread_create(&th2, NULL, th2_main, &how);
    if (error)
        die(error, "pthread_create th2");
    /* now wait for threads */
    error = pthread_join(th1, NULL);
    error = pthread_join(th2, NULL);
    printf("joined, normal exit\n");
    return 0;
}

void *th1_main(void *arg) {
    struct behave *how = arg;

    WR("thread 1 start\n");
    (void) pthread_mutex_lock(&global_mtx);
    (void) pthread_mutex_lock(&how->lock);
    how->th1_entered = 1;
    pthread_cond_signal(&how->cond);
    while (how->th2_entered == 0)
        (void) pthread_cond_wait(&how->cond, &how->lock);
    WR("thread 1 sees thread 2 started\n");
    (void) pthread_mutex_unlock(&how->lock);
    if (how->how == EXIT_W_HANG)
        WR("thread 1 not unlocking\n");
    else
        (void) pthread_mutex_unlock(&global_mtx);
    return NULL;
}

void *th2_main(void *arg) {
    struct behave *how = arg;

    WR("thread 2 start\n");
    (void) pthread_mutex_lock(&how->lock);
    how->th2_entered = 1;
    pthread_cond_signal(&how->cond);
    while (how->th1_entered == 0)
        (void) pthread_cond_wait(&how->cond, &how->lock);
    WR("thread 2 sees thread 1 started\n");
    (void) pthread_mutex_unlock(&how->lock);
    if (how->how != NORMAL) {
        WR("thread 2 exit()\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    return NULL;
}

void hanger(void) {
    /* this is what will cause us to hang, in the one case */
    WR("hanger start\n");
    pthread_mutex_lock(&global_mtx);
    WR("hanger got global mutex\n");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&global_mtx);
    WR("hanger finish\n");
}
```

Comment: I've asked a related question here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12549704/glibc-possible-race-condition-between-closing-file-while-exiting , some variations of that race condition can just as easy lead to a deadlock, and hang the process too. (note that exit() is similar to returning from main )

Comment: For what it's worth, in my own stdio code (written long before POSIX threading even existed), I have my at-exit cleanup code merely `fflush` all files, not `fclose` them.  This does not prevent all problems, it just makes the "thread uses closed stdio stream" not occur.  (Wasn't actually *planning* that when I wrote it, just going for efficiency: `_exit` frees all memory and closes all files, so why make extra syscalls?)

Comment: There is also the possibility of a hang in the `_fini()` function of a shared library because some mutex has not yet been released, or the global state that the `_fini()` function is operating on is not in a consistent state.